# List of tables horizontal space too small

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, koma-script

I have the following issue: I would like to label my tables for part of the document differently, based on subsections. I am using the code `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{table}}` for it. That works fine. But when I create the LOT, the spacing seems off - the caption touches the number of the table to the left for the table with number 10. Is there anything that can be done?
I am also flexible for other solutions than using `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{table}}`, but it works nicely. If I am not mistaken, that is not the problem.
The solution must work with `scrreprt`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    \listoftables
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{table}}
    
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    \makeatletter
    \@whilenum\value{table}<10\do{%
        \captionof{table}{This is test table \thetable}
    }
    \makeatother
    
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any hints.
Edit: I tried `listof=flat`. It works nicely, but in some cases of longer table headings, it seems to reach a bit too far to the right. Edit: The indentation is wrong using this approach (when the caption reaches over two line, indentation is not right). Therefore this solution is not recommended. Any alternatives?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you use `\Alph{section}` in the definition of `\thetable` even though `section` numbers use arabic numerals?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that in the above example, but for the answer it should not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{table}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{table}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{table}}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\captionof{table}{This is test table \thetable}
\setcounter{table}{9}
\captionof{table}{This is test table \thetable}
\captionof{table}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

You could also change the `indent`:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth,indent=0pt]{tocline}{table}
```

[image]

But if you need `dynnumwidth,indent=0pt` for both figures and tables

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[dynnumwidth,indent=0pt]{tocline}{figure,table}
```

you could also use class option `listof=flat`:

```latex
\documentclass[listof=flat]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{table}}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\captionof{table}{This is test table \thetable}
\setcounter{table}{9}
\captionof{table}{This is test table \thetable}
\captionof{table}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Comment: thank you exactly what I needed. Did not know this was included in koma script. Just one question: What is `dynnumwidth`? The manual doesn't say much about it, and you use it for the width.

Comment: `dynnumwidth` ensures that there is enough space for the numbers: if the value of `numwidth` (fixed number width) is to low for the widest number plus `numsep` (minimum space between number and text) than the width of the widest number plus `\numsep` is used as number width for all entries of this type.

Comment: ah very helpful indeed, thanks for the explanation.